# How can I handle these weird special characters messing my print formatting?

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, string-formatting, python-unicode

I am printing a formatted table.  But sometimes these user generated characters are taking more than one character width and it messes up the formatting as you can see in the screenshot below...

[image]

The width of the "title" column is formatted to be 68 bytes.  But these "special characters" are taking up more than 1 character width but are only counted as 1 character.  This pushes the column past its bounds.

```
print('{0:16s}{3:<18s}{1:68s}{2:>8n}'.format((
    ' ' + streamer['user_name'][:12] + '..') if len(streamer['user_name']) > 12 else ' ' + streamer['user_name'],
    (streamer['title'].strip()[:62] + '..') if len(streamer['title']) > 62 else streamer['title'].strip(),
    streamer['viewer_count'],
    (gamesDic[streamer['game_id']][:15] + '..') if len(gamesDic[streamer['game_id']]) > 15 else gamesDic[streamer['game_id']]))
```

Any advice on how to deal with these special characters?

**edit:**  I printed the offending string to file.

> ( ) ✨  ＬＩＶＥ  SUBS GET SNAPCHAT

**edit2:**

Why do these not align on a character boundary?

[image]

**edit3:**

Today the first two characters are producing weird output.  But the columns are aligned in each case below.

First character in isolation...

`title[0]`

[image]

Second character in isolation... `title[1]`

[image]

First and second character together..  `title[0] + title[1]`

[image: first and second character]

Comment: Can you add to your code `streamer` and `gameDic` values?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make those characters take up the same width as the other characters or are you looking for a way to align the columns without changing those characters?

Comment: Interesting question lol (cause I'm not  sure).  My first priority is to not break the table.  Second priority is to display the text as the user intended.  So whichever one can satisfy both.

Comment: @Alderven they are just strings I got from the Twitch API.  `streamer['title']` is just a string.

Comment: Any way can you share it? I want to debug those symbols

Comment: @Alderven I included the offending string and characters in the edit above.

Comment: [Have a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30896091/5320601) - that should help to find the width of the characters at least, from there it might be possible to accomplish what you want.

Comment: The characters in "ＬＩＶＥ" are [Fullwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) characters.   A hacky way to deal with them might be to test their width with `unicodedata.east_asian_width(char)`  (it will return "F" for fullwidth characters) and substitute with the final character of `unicodedata.name(char)` (or just count them as length 2)

Comment: @snakecharmerb do you have any ideas on how to solve "half character width" problem?

Comment: My terminal is using "ubuntu mono regular".

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52932719/5320906) gives some insight on the trickiness of unicode formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written custom string formatter based on @snakecharmerb`s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54821769/how-can-i-handle-these-weird-special-characters-messing-my-print-formatting#comment96420934_54821769) but still "half character width" problem persist:

```
import unicodedata

def fstring(string, max_length, align='l'):
    string = str(string)
    extra_length = 0
    for char in string:
        if unicodedata.east_asian_width(char) == 'F':
            extra_length += 1

    diff = max_length - len(string) - extra_length
    if diff > 0:
        return string + diff * ' ' if align == 'l' else diff * ' ' + string
    elif diff < 0:
        return string[:max_length-3] + '.. '

    return string

data = [{'user_name': 'shroud', 'game_id': 'Apex Legends', 'title': 'pathfinder twitch prime loot YAYA @shroud on socials for update', 'viewer_count': 66200},
        {'user_name': 'Amouranth', 'game_id': 'ASMR', 'title': '  ( ) ✨ ＬＩＶＥ  SUBS GET SNAPCHAT', 'viewer_count': 2261}]

for d in data:
    name = fstring(d['user_name'], 20)
    game_id = fstring(d['game_id'], 15)
    title = fstring(d['title'], 62)
    count = fstring(d['viewer_count'], 10, align='r')
    print('{}{}{}{}'.format(name, game_id, title, count))
```

It produces output:

[image]

(can't post it as a text since formatting will be lost)

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It seems they still don't align perfectly, as if they are off by half a character.  I get the same results when I type it over a non offending string if you see "edit2:" above.

Comment: Have no ideas how to solve. I've asked @snakecharmerb about that.

Answer (score 3):

I made this comment to the question:

> The characters in "ＬＩＶＥ" are [Fullwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_fullwidth_forms) characters. A hacky way to
>   deal with them might be to test their width with
>   `unicodedata.east_asian_width(char)` (it will return "F" for fullwidth
>   characters) and substitute with the final character of
>   `unicodedata.name(char)` (or just count them as length 2)

This "answer" is essentially another comment, but too long for the comment field.

This hack - as implemented in Alderven's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54828570/5320906) - almost works for the OP, but the example string is rendered with an extra half a character width (note the example string does not contain any East Asian halfwidth characters.).

I am unable to reproduce this exact behaviour, using this test statement, where `s` is the example string from the question, varying the characters removed:

```
print((s + (68 - (len(s) + sum(1 for x in s if ud.east_asian_width(x) in ('F', 'N', 'W')))) * 'x')+ '\n'+ ('x' * 68))
```

In a Python 3.6 interpreter in a Gnome terminal on Debian, using the default monospace regular font, removing full-width characters causes the example string to apparently render three characters longer than 
the equivalent string of "x"s.

Removing full-width and wide (East Asian Width "W") characters produced a string that appeared to render the same length as the equivalent number of "x"s.

In a Python 3.7 KDE Konsole terminal on OpenSuse, using Ubuntu Monospace regular font, I could not produce a string that rendered the same length regardless of the combination of full-width, wide or neutral ("N") characters that I removed.

I did notice that in the sparkles character (✨) seemed to take up an extra half a width when rendered alone in Konsole, but could not see any half a width differences when testing the full string.

I suspect that the problem is low-level rendering outside the control of Python , as this note on the Unicode [standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/#Scope) suggests:

> **Note:** The East_Asian_Width property is not intended for use by modern
>   terminal emulators without appropriate tailoring on a case-by-case
>   basis. Such terminal emulators need a way to resolve the
>   halfwidth/fullwidth dichotomy that is necessary for such environments,
>   but the East_Asian_Width property does not provide an off-the-shelf
>   solution for all situations. The growing repertoire of the Unicode
>   Standard has long exceeded the bounds of East Asian legacy character
>   encodings, and terminal emulations often need to be customized to
>   support edge cases and for changes in typographical behavior over
>   time.

Comment: NB I have no problem with Alderven answering the question using my comment.